# unable to attachevent to a row using a dom

Tags: javascript, dom

```
function addRow(names,count) {

    deleteRow();
    var table = dataTable;

    for(var i=0;i<count;i++)
    {

         var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

        var cell2 = row.insertCell(0);
        cell2.innerHTML = rowCount;

        var cell3 = row.insertCell(1);
        var element2 = document.createElement('tr');
        var element3 = document.createElement('td');
        //element2.type = "text";
        element2.appendChild(element3)
        cell3.appendChild(element2);
        cell3.innerHTML = names[i];
        element3.attachEvent("test()", onclick);

    }
}
```

this is my code sample, i'm unable to attach event to either element2 or element3,
can anybody help me out, what the problem with this

this is the one more sample i tried out, it contains complete code..

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <TITLE> Add/Remove dynamic rows in HTML table </TITLE>
    <SCRIPT language="javascript">
        function addRow(tableID) {

            var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

            var rowCount = table.rows.length;
            var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

            var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
            var element1 = document.createElement("input");
            element1.type = "checkbox";
            cell1.appendChild(element1);

            var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
            cell2.innerHTML = rowCount + 1;

            var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
            var element2 = document.createElement("input");
            element2.type = "text";
            cell3.appendChild(element2);
            element2.attachEvent("onclick",function(){ alert("event triggered"); });


        }

        function deleteRow(tableID) {
            try {
            var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
            var rowCount = table.rows.length;

            for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {
                var row = table.rows[i];
                var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
                if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
                    var index = table.rowIndex;
                    alert("index"+index);
                    //table.deleteRow(i);
                    //rowCount--;
                    i--;
                }

            }
            }catch(e) {
                alert(e);
            }
        }

    </SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY>

    <INPUT type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" />

    <INPUT type="button" value="Delete Row" onclick="deleteRow('dataTable')" />

    <TABLE id="dataTable" width="350px" border="1">
        <TR>
            <TD><INPUT type="checkbox" name="chk"/></TD>
            <TD> 1 </TD>
            <TD> <INPUT type="text" /> </TD>
        </TR>
    </TABLE>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: We're going to need more information.  Do you have more script or HTML to show us?  As it stands now, `deleteRow()` and `dataTable` are undefined.

Comment: deleteRow doesnt contain any html, and var table = dataTable; fetches the tableid

Comment: In which browser you tested it?

Comment: You should include some of the sample data so we can test it out.  That way we can run this code the way you are running it, get the same errors, so we can debug it easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logic and syntax error, heres the breakdown.

```
cell3.appendChild(element2); // appends your element
cell3.innerHTML = names[i]; // deletes element2 and replaces it with names[i]
```

`element2` doesn't exist because you set everything inside `cell3` to be `names[i]` after you appended `element2`.

You also need to update the event binding (IE)

```
element3.attachEvent("onclick", function(){ /* code */ });
```

Comment: Ok, but if i dont use this way, i cant print the value inside a row

Comment: I'm guessing you want the value in the TD cell because its invalid markup putting text inside a <tr> and outside the <td> Try this: `element3.innerHTML = names[i]`

Comment: ya i wanted value inside a td, but the value wont get displayed if used it that way

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
 element3.onclick = function () {
               test();
            }
```

Comment: what happens when you try this..??

Comment: element3.addEventListener('onclick', function (e) {
  //your code
}, false);